# Using VueJS throughout entire Laravel app

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to remove any blade templates from my Laravel project, so this includes the homepage.  I have left myself `app.blade.php` which contains the following

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>My Website</title>

    <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <Navigation></Navigation>
    <div class="container">
        <main>
            <router-view></router-view>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So a Navigation Component and a router-view.  I have installed the router package.  Within `web.php` I have:

```php
Route::get('/{any}', function(){
    return view('layouts.app');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

**`Navigation.vue`** is simple:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <router-link to="/" tag="a" class="nav-link" active-class="active" exact>
                        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                        <p>
                            Website Name
                        </p>
                    </router-link>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <router-link to="/dashboard" tag="a" class="nav-link" active-class="active" exact>
                        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                        <p>
                            Dashboards
                        </p>
                    </router-link>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

I also have a couple of basic components: `App.vue` and `Dashboard.vue` that contain basic templates. And then in `app.js` I have:

```js
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

import Navigation from './components/Navigation';

let routes = [
    { path: '/', component: require('./components/App.vue').default },
    { path: '/dashboard', component: require('./components/Dashboard.vue').default }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { Navigation },
    router
});
```

So when I visit my `localhost:8000` I see a mostly empty page besides the navigation, as to be expected.  However, when I click on the link, the content of a sample component is not being displayed, even though the url is changing. For example, `Dashboard` component is:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <main>
            <h1>This is a dashboard</h1>
        </main>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

Is there any reason within my setup why it is not displaying the content by clicking the navigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `require(...).default` is required by `vue-loader@15` which included in `laravel-mix@4`. If you're using previous versions of `laravel-mix` (as it seems) you should not add `.default`:

```js
let routes = [
    { path: '/', component: require('./components/App.vue') },
    { path: '/dashboard', component: require('./components/Dashboard.vue') }
];
```

Comment: Hi thanks, that seems to work.  Why does this work?  A lot of the tutorials I have followed use the .default

Comment: @kate_hudson I think you're confusing it with dynamic imports: `import(...).default`

Comment: @kate_hudson It also depends on `laravel-mix` version you're using. Prior to 4.0 it was `require()`, but since 4.0 you should use `require().default`. https://laravel-mix.com/docs/4.0/upgrade#importing-es-modules

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I was working with the latest, then downgraded to Laravel 5.5 because there is no stable release of PHP 7.1 for our server, that explains it